# Multi-tenant database for SAAS application

Tags: database-design, multi-tenant, saas

I am developing a SAAS application which will have several thousand customers, and each customer, in turn, will have 10-20 of their own customers.

Currently implementing one-database-for-all-customers, but I am concerned about privacy/security and complexity of thousands of tables in just one database.  Is there any downside to **dedicating a database to each customer**?

If that is a better approach, are there database platforms that do a good job at it? AWS RDS with Postgre SQL?  I am a novice programmer currently using PHP + MySQL.

Thank you!

Comment: The downside of dedicating a database to each customer is managing several thousand databases.  One database for all customers is what Walmart and other retailers use.

Comment: Thank you, @GilbertLeBlanc! So managing one db/customer requires backup, data cleanup, version upgrades, scheduling, performance monitoring etc for each one of thousands of DB.  Which will require a professional plan/tool/team to carry out.  On the other hand, one db for all customers will get complex in terms of managing the schema, assuring proper security and privacy of each customer's data etc.  So that has to be designed very carefully.  But if done properly, then a single db will be easier to manage than thousands?  Thanks again!

Comment: you can try to use a single database also with sharding by tenant so that the load is evenly distributed across shards

Comment: Hi Sarvanan, Thanks! Looked into Sharding and sounds quite useful.  Especially to prevent heavy DB users from reducing performance for others.  Is there a DB platform that makes sharding easier? Read that MongoDB is good at it? Thanks again!